# Undefined result when parse xml to json with xml2js node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, xml, xml2js

i got a problem when parsing an XML to JSON by using [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js). Here's my xml.

```
<Tables>
<Table>
    <Id>TABLE1</Id>
    <Description>Test 1</Description>
    <FullName>TEST.CHEM.Customer</FullName>
    <Columns>
    <Column>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Name>CustomerId</Name>
        <DataType>Number</DataType>
    </Column>
    <Column>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Name>CustomerName</Name>
        <DataType>String</DataType>
    </Column>
    <Column>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Name>ValidFrom</Name>
        <DataType>Date</DataType>
    </Column>
    </Columns>
</Table></Tables>
```

And here's my main. I follow snippet from that library for the `figuredOutXML (input: xmlfile.parseString, output: data)`

```
apiRoutes.get('/test', function(req, res) {
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

figuredOutXML(function(err,data,data2){
    if(err){
        console.log("Error!");
        console.error(err.message);
    }else{
        var tableId = util.inspect(data2.Tables.Table.Id, false, null);
        res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({
        INFO: 'SUCCESS',
        TABLE: tableId}));
    }

});
```

But i got undefined result for `tableId`. Is it something wrong with xml or the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was carelessness, it will always undefined result because `var tableId` is string formatted not on JSON format see [here](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options), so when xml already parsed by xml2js parser it already json formatted. You can access it by `result.Databases.Tables[0].Table[0].FullName` based on above xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with another package [camaro](http://npmjs.com/package/camaro) with simply and easily change the desired result.

Example:

```
const xml = '<Tables>
<Table>
    <Id>TABLE1</Id>
    <Description>Test 1</Description>
    <FullName>TEST.CHEM.Customer</FullName>
    <Columns>
    <Column>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Name>CustomerId</Name>
        <DataType>Number</DataType>
    </Column>
    <Column>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Name>CustomerName</Name>
        <DataType>String</DataType>
    </Column>
    <Column>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Name>ValidFrom</Name>
        <DataType>Date</DataType>
    </Column>
    </Columns>
</Table></Tables>'

const temp = {
    table_id: 'Tables/Table/Id'
    columns: ['/Tables/Table/Columns/Column', {
        column_id: 'Id',
        name: 'Name'
    }]
}

const transform = require('camaro')
const results = transform(xml, temp)

console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2))
```

Results

```
{
    "columns": [
        {
        "column_id": "1",
        "name": "CustomerId"
        },
        {
        "column_id": "2",
        "name": "CustomerName"
        },
        {
        "column_id": "2",
        "name": "ValidFrom"
        }
    ],
    "table_id": "TABLE1"
}
```

Comment: it is more convenient than my previous answer, is it you are the maker of [camaro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/camaro)? btw, thanks a lot @anh-thang-bui

Comment: i'm not, the maker are my friend